# How to solve hang issue of zendstudio 13.6 while comparing js file

Tags: eclipse, svn, zend-studio

I am using Zendstudio 13.6 from past 2-3 weeks. I am facing hang issue on my linux system while comparing js files using team synchronization svn compare. Similar issue happens when opening xsd file in editor.

I just checked process using top command. I saw cpu usage gets 100% in such case and memory usage is normal 18% max. If there were memory issue I could try to increase heap memory using eclipse.ini file.

Does anyone faced this issue? If yes how can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. And I solved it like this.
Possibly what happens is that when you try to open a XSD file, the editor tries to find a print feature to build up the design solution.

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.disablePrinting

Enter the line mentioned above in the ZendStudio.ini file of your Zend Installation folder. And restart your ZendStudio Editor.

You will be easily able to open the xsd file and it will not freeze your editor.

And about the JS freeze problem, There is some other solution to JS freeze problem. Will update you once I find it.

Comment: Thanks @code-buster, XSD issue is fixed using above mentioned changes. I am waiting for your solution for JS freeze problem.

Comment: At the moment I could not find much.May be you can check all installed plugins that run in background and remove the ones not needed.
Also when comparing a JS file (When IDE is in PHP mode), 
Option 1: Instead of clicking RightClick + Commit, I would do a 
RightClickOnProjectFolder > Team > Synchronise with Repository option. You will see outgoing changes.
RightClick on JS file, choose "Open in external compare editor". Most of the times, if the JS file is not too huge, It opens up in compare editor.
Option 2: Otherwise, last option is to use online JS compare tool for file comparisons.

Comment: I am currently using first option which you have mentioned. It is working in all cases so far.